# Cheap option for recording HDMI output

Tags: video-capture

I have been looking for a way for my PC to record HDMI output so I can record my gaming console without buying an expensive capture card. I already have a HDMI splitter I'm just looking for some cheap software.

Comment: This question would probably be better suited on the Hardware Recommendations site.

Answer (score 1):

An HDMI splitter is not what you need. You need either an HDMI capture card, or a standalone HDMI video recorder. The cheapest HDMI video recorder you're going to find is the Atomos Ninja Star, for $250 on B&H: https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1285811-REG/atomos_atomnjs001_64_ninja_star_recorder_with.html

HDMI capture cards start around $130. Here is a good one from Blackmagic, for $137.50 on B&H: https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/964122-REG/blackmagic_design_decklink_mini_recorder.html